# Set notifications to be displayed on external monitor - MacOS

Tags: macos, notifications

Ive got 2 external monitors connected to Macbook Pro running Big Sur.

I run the 2 external monitors and the laptop screen in a 3 screen configuration.

Is it possible to set my notifications for emails etc to pop up to one of the external monitors when connected rather than to the laptop ? (Although id still like for the notifications to pop up to the laptop when only using the laptop)